# Newer versions of both AngularJS and Firebase, yet I am still getting TypeError: $cookies.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, cookies

```js
(function() {
    function uCtrl($uibModalInstance, $cookies) {

        var saveUser = function(username) {
            $cookies.put('blocChatCurrentUser', 'username');
        };

        var getUser = function() {
            return $cookies.get('blocChatCurrentUser');
        };

        this.isValid = function() {
          var currentUser = getUser();
          if(!currentUser === undefined) {
              currentUser = currentUser.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
          }
          else if(currentUser === '' || currentUser === undefined) {
              this.currentUserError = 'Username Cannot Be Empty';
              this.currentUserErrorTrue = true;
              this.setUsername.name = '';
              return;
          }
          else {
              $cookies.blocChatCurrentUser = currentUser;
              saveUser(currentUser);
              $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
          }
        };
    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .controller('uCtrl', ['$cookies', '$uibModalInstance', uCtrl]);
})();
```

```html
<div>
    <div class = "modal-header">
        <h2 class = "modal-title">Set A Username</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "modal-body">
        <br>This name will appear when you send messages.</br>
        <form name = "Username" ng-submit = "cookieThis.isValid()">
            <div class = "input-group animated">
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control finderBar" ng-model = "this.username" name = "username" ng-minlength = "1" required autofocus>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class = "modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click= "cookieThis.isValid()" ng-disabled = "this.username == null">Set Username</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

All the other files work perfectly fine. ModalInstanceCtrl and ModalCtrl all have been tested with respective .html files and they work. So basically, I am trying to take the user provided username and store it in a cookie. Of course, there are getUser() and setUser() method for using the cookie.

Comment: `$uibModalInstance, $cookies` and  `'$cookies', '$uibModalInstance'` <-- does order matter?

Comment: @epascarello No the order doesn't matter. I have already tried changing the order.